# Proof check for $(A\setminus B)\times X=(A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove: $(A\setminus B)\times X=(A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)$

**Proof:**

1. Let $p\in (A\setminus B)\times X$.
2. $p=(a,x)$ for some $a\in A$ and $a\notin B$ and $x\in X$.
3. $p\in A\times X$
4. If $p\in B\times X$ then $a\in B$. Contradiction.
5. $p \notin B\times X$.
6. $p\in (A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)$.
7. $(A\setminus B)\times X\subset (A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)$.

Other direction:

1. Let $p\in (A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)$.
2. $p=(a,x)$ for some $a\in A$ and $x\in X$ and $p\notin B\times X$.
3. If $a\in B$ then $p\in B\times X$. Contradiction.
4. $a\notin B$.
5. $p=(a,x)$ for some $a\in A$ and $a\notin B$ and $x\in X$.
6. $p=(a,x)$ for some $a\in A\setminus B$ and $x\in X$.
7. $p\in (A\setminus B)\times X$.
8. $(A\times X)\setminus(B\times X)\subset (A\setminus B)\times X$.

---

***Note:***

I’m resorting to this type of proof coz I don’t know the formal proof methods for quantifiers. I’d be glad if you could point me to some good resource for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The equation:

(A-B) * X = (A * X) - (B * X)

is only true if a simple multiplicative distributive property is allowed in your math.  For example, the equation above would be true if the variables A,B, and X were real numbers (multiplicative distributive is closed under the set of real numbers).  The answer would be different if A,B, and X were matrix.

Or maybe you don't care about the answer, but you want a proof using logic or something?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MathSE! What I’m asking is in context to set theory.

Comment: @Crash Magnet : you have misunderstood the issue : the minus sign is the minus sign of set theory :$\smallsetminus$ and should have been written so.

Comment: I suspected something like that since you use all those funny symbols in your proof. Good luck with your question.